# Square Webhook to provide my application with a digital receipt of a purchase a user made

Tags: node.js, api, square-connect, square, receipt

I'm trying to find a way for Square API to notify my application (maybe using webhooks) of the user's receipt.

I'm still trying to wrap my heads around all the APIs provided by Square. I'm particularly looking at the Orders API. Frankly, it's hard to understand what each API does with all the technical jargon mentioned.

Here's what I want to happen. Initially, my user provides some credentials (say email, or even credit card). When a user purchased something via Square, I expect Square API to send the receipt information to my application. Square knows that that receipt corresponds to the user because the user used the same email/credit card when purchasing item in Square with the one they use for the application.

Answer (score 0):

Currently Square's APIs do not send a receipt after a purchase is completed. Unfortunately, if you want a receipt emailed to your customer, you'll need to build out that functionality yourself (there's no way to do it with Square's APIs).

With that said, you can use the [V1 Payments API](https://docs.connect.squareup.com/api/connect/v2#endpoint-v1transactions-listpayments) to list the `receipt_url`. Again, it will not automatically be emailed to the customer, but you could provide the URL to your customer in your own way.